# WebRTC android application is creating echo when earphones are connected

Tags: android, webrtc, android-audiomanager, webrtc-android

Peer connection is getting established between devices and people on either side are able to have communication. No issue is happening when the **EARPIECE** is used by anyone or both of the devices.

Problem is occurring when **EARPHONES** or **INBUILT_SPEAKER** is used for audio communication by both devices.

Dependency: `'org.webrtc:google-webrtc:1.0.30039'`

I have already tried the below options

**OPTION-1**

```
audioConstraints.mandatory.add(new MediaConstraints.KeyValuePair("googEchoCancellation", "true"));
audioConstraints.mandatory.add(new MediaConstraints.KeyValuePair("googEchoCancellation2", "true"));
audioConstraints.mandatory.add(new MediaConstraints.KeyValuePair("googDAEchoCancellation", "true"));
audioConstraints.mandatory.add(new MediaConstraints.KeyValuePair("googTypingNoiseDetection", "true"));
audioConstraints.mandatory.add(new MediaConstraints.KeyValuePair("googAutoGainControl", "true"));
audioConstraints.mandatory.add(new MediaConstraints.KeyValuePair("googAutoGainControl2", "true"));
audioConstraints.mandatory.add(new MediaConstraints.KeyValuePair("googNoiseSuppression", "true"));
audioConstraints.mandatory.add(new MediaConstraints.KeyValuePair("googNoiseSuppression2", "true"));
audioConstraints.mandatory.add(new MediaConstraints.KeyValuePair("googAudioMirroring", "false"));
audioConstraints.mandatory.add(new MediaConstraints.KeyValuePair("googHighpassFilter", "true"));
```

**OPTION-2**

```
JavaAudioDeviceModule.builder ( mContext )
                .setUseHardwareAcousticEchoCanceler(false)
                .setUseHardwareNoiseSuppressor(false)
                .createAudioDeviceModule ();
WebRtcAudioUtils.setWebRtcBasedNoiseSuppressor ( true );
WebRtcAudioUtils.setWebRtcBasedAcousticEchoCanceler ( true );
WebRtcAudioUtils.setWebRtcBasedAutomaticGainControl ( true );
```

Kindly help me figure out what is missing. How can I eliminate or reduce this echo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following two steps solved the issue.

AudioDeviceModule was added to PeerConnectionFactory.

```
private PeerConnectionFactory createPeerConnectionFactory () {
        AudioDeviceModule audioDeviceModule = JavaAudioDeviceModule.builder ( mContext )
                .setUseHardwareAcousticEchoCanceler ( false )
                .setUseHardwareNoiseSuppressor ( false )
                .createAudioDeviceModule ();
        PeerConnectionFactory.InitializationOptions initializationOptions = PeerConnectionFactory.InitializationOptions.builder ( mContext )
                .createInitializationOptions ();
        PeerConnectionFactory.initialize ( initializationOptions );
        peerConnectionFactory = PeerConnectionFactory.builder ()
                .setAudioDeviceModule ( audioDeviceModule )
                .createPeerConnectionFactory ();
        return peerConnectionFactory;
    }
```

WebRTC based noise suppressor and echo canceller were enabled while creating audio stream

```
private void createLocalStream () {
        WebRtcAudioUtils.setWebRtcBasedNoiseSuppressor ( true );
        WebRtcAudioUtils.setWebRtcBasedAcousticEchoCanceler ( true );
        WebRtcAudioUtils.setWebRtcBasedAutomaticGainControl ( true );
        MediaConstraints localMediaConstraints = new MediaConstraints ();
        AudioSource localAudioSource = peerConnectionFactory.createAudioSource ( localMediaConstraints );
        localTrack = peerConnectionFactory.createAudioTrack ( LOCAL_AUDIO_TRACK, localAudioSource );
        localTrack.setEnabled ( true );
        localMediaStream = peerConnectionFactory.createLocalMediaStream ( LOCAL_STREAM );
        localMediaStream.addTrack ( localTrack );
        peerConnection.addStream ( localMediaStream );
    }
```

Comment: so you didn't use the Audio MediaConstraints at all?

Comment: Is the full sample code available for these codes?